# Como cambiar el valor de un mock en tiempo de ejecucion?

Tags: java, spring, test, junit

Tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
public void ingresarCarga() {

    Integer idCarga = ingresoDao.ingresar();
    ResultadoIngreso resultado;

    do {
        resultado = archivoDao.procesar();
        try {
            if(resultado.getCodigo() == 1){
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.info("InterruptedException");
        } 
    }while (resultado.getCodigo() == 1);
}
```

Claramente se puede notar que se puede entrar en un loop infinito, pero el codigo no esta incorrecto. Al tratar de hacer los tests de cobertura me encuentro con el problema el tratar de cubrir el caso cuando la respuesta es -60.

He tratado de diversas maneras y ninguna me ha funcionado:

```
    @Test(timeout=11000, expected = Exception.class)
    public void testIngreso2() throws Exception {
        Integer retorno = 1;

        Mockito.when(archivoDao.procesar()).thenReturn(resultado);
        Mockito.when(resultado.getCodigo()).thenReturn(retorno);

        instancia.ingresarCarga();
}
```

En este caso falla el test y devuelve el siguiente error:

*java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 11000 milliseconds
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)*

También pensé en una forma de cambiar el valor del retorno en la segunda iteracion pero hasta ahora no lo he podido conseguir.

Estoy trabajando con java 7 y junit 4.11

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano :D.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que archivoDao y resultado están bien inyectados en instancia?

Answer (score -3):

Retornando dos valores en el `thenReturn`:

```
Mockito.when(metodo).thenReturn(valor 1,valor 2);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución pero esta publicación fue reportada como de "baja calidad", te sugiero revisar [answer] en base a esto modifica tu publicación, agrega una explicación del código, ¿como ayudaría a solucionar el problema ?, saludos.